# Load an applet with specified older JRE version instead of latest installed

Tags: applet, java, classnotfoundexception

I wish to load my applet with JRE version 1.6.0_14. I have installed updates 14, 17, 24 and 35. I am using `<object>` tag with `classid` to load version with update 14.

in this case, the applet get loaded with update 35 and then again with update 14. on the java console on update 35 no error noticed and on Java console of update 1.6.0_14 we see the following error.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun/net/www/protocol/http/NTLMAuthenticationCallback
```

How to avoid higher version JRE to be used? And how to avoid the class not found error?

Comment: Ensuring a particular version won't be enough to solve the problem.  A non Oracle JRE would likely not have a class in the `sun` package.  The fix is ***don't use the classes in the `sun` package in the first place*** though I thought the compiler warnings and a little research should have been sufficient to determine that much.

Comment: As an aside. 1) Use your shift/caps. key where appropriate.  Reading all lower case is like trying to listen to someone mumbling. 2) Review what you are about to post to the forum.  If you had, you might have noticed that `<object>` does not render unless it is wrapped in ` characters.

Comment: I haven't used this NTLMAuthenticationCallback class neither the sun package. The Exception stack doesn't show any of my fucntion.

Answer (score 1):

It is a serious security risk to run with a lower version of the JRE. Not when you run your own applet, cause you trust your own code. But others ought to refuse running it. You, yourself, should be wary when browsing the net with a browser that does not have the latest version of the JRE installed.

The JRE installer installs the Java Plugin into your browser and one single version of the Plug-in will always be started, independent of the Java version you request. The Plugin will then run the applet in the JRE that is specified in the classid of your object tag. The versions available to the Plug-in are configurable in the Java Control Panel.

This leaves the question of why your application won't run with a recent version of java 1.6. The Plugin got a big overhaul in 1.6.0_something into what's called the Next Generation Plug-in. Maybe that is what is giving you trouble. You can indicate that you wish to use the old Plug-in on your machine in the Java Control Panel on the advanced tab. ("Enable the Next Generation Java Plug-in (requires a Browser restart"). I'd think it's interesting to know if disabling the Next Generation Plug-in solves your issue.